# How to find percentage change in values of a column using a variable for another column with pandas "category" data type?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Here's the data frame:

[image]

```
df_temp = pd.DataFrame({'pos': {0: '1-10',
  1: '11-20',
  2: '21-30',
  3: '31-40',
  4: '41-50',
  5: '51-60',
  6: '61-70',
  7: '71-80',
  8: '81-90',
  9: '91-100',
  10: '101-110'},
 'imp': {0: 18647,
  1: 566,
  2: 157,
  3: 61,
  4: 343,
  5: 464,
  6: 225,
  7: 238,
  8: 852,
  9: 108,
  10: 0}})

df_temp
```

In my notebook, df.dtypes show:

[image]

I don't know how to put such data type through a dict.

Now if "pos" of x goes up from say 73 to 15.
Required function:

```
def percent_change(73, 15):
    => 238*(x/100) = 566  #imp at 71-80 = 238 and 11-20 = 566
    => x = (566*100)/238
    => x = 100 - x # Mayby? To show only change?
    return x
```

Edit: My embarrassing solution, simply did string operation:

```
def p_change(x, y, df):
    
    if len(str(x)) == 1:
        x = 0
    elif int(str(x)[1]) == 0:
        x = int(str(x)[0]) - 1
    else:
        x = int(str(x)[0])

    if len(str(y)) == 1:
        y = 0
    elif int(str(y)[1]) == 0:
        y = int(str(y)[0]) - 1
    else:
        y = int(str(y)[0])
        
    x = int(df.loc[x, 'Impressions'])
    y = int(df.loc[y, 'Impressions'])
    p_change = print('Percentage change: ' + str(round(((y*100)/x - 100), 2)) + '%')
    
    return p_change
```

Comment: Mystic, Can you explain the logic?

Comment: 1) why not to try something like `x // 10; y // 10` to get the index? 2) IMO the percentage is better as a coefficient, while when printing we can use formatting like `print(f"Percentage change: {y/x - 1:.2%}")`

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have some sequence of ages and a refference table between age bins and some value *imp*:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(42)

N = 10    # number of data
data = pd.Series(rng.integers(1, 111, N), name='Ages')

imp = pd.Series(
    data=[18647, 566, 157, 61, 343, 464, 225, 238, 852, 108, 0],
    index=pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks(range(0,111,10)).rename('pos'),
    name='imp'
)
```

Now we want to replace each age with the corresponding *imp* value. To do this we have to categorize ages like `imp.index` first, see [pandas.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html#pandas.cut):

```
m = pd.cut(data, imp.index).map(imp).astype(imp.dtype)
```

Now we are ready to calculate the relative difference along a data sequence:

```
output = m.shift(-1)/m - 1    # multiply by 100 if needed
```

---

#### ps.

I'm not sure if it's a good idea to store the data as a percentage, like `"10.05%"`, etc. In my opinion, it's much better to store it as a ratio that can be used in further arithmetic operations. When printing the result on the screen or paper, we can always turn to formatting tools for help:

```
output.to_frame().style.format('{:.2%}')   
output.to_string(float_format="{:.2%}".format)
```

Comment: You solved half the problem, approach is very intelligent but didn't get the percentage increase/decrease right. My stupid function (added in question now) is somehow getting it for now.